# Ler arquivo xml pronto

Tags: c#, xml

Eae pessoal, to tentado ler um arquivo xml no meu programa, mas tem uma linha que não estou conseguindo ler.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML>
<PATCHINFO>
 <PATCHNODE file="./Unit1.dfm">
  <SIZE>2962</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>4206740436</CHECKSUM>
 </PATCHNODE>
 <PATCHNODE file="./Unit1.pas">
  <SIZE>5124</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>2933818657</CHECKSUM>
 </PATCHNODE>
 <PATCHNODE file="./atch.pas">
  <SIZE>4286</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>1112274213</CHECKSUM>
 </PATCHNODE>
 <PATCHNODE file="./teste.dpr">
  <SIZE>252</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>3715331657</CHECKSUM>
 </PATCHNODE>
 <PATCHNODE file="./teste2.res">
  <SIZE>1572</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>1544128681</CHECKSUM>
 </PATCHNODE>
</PATCHINFO>
</XML>
```

Meu codigo está editado para a xml abaixo

```
            int curr_array_element = 0;
            Hash hash = new Hash();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Patch.xml");
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList allFiles = root.GetElementsByTagName("PATCHINFO");
            foreach (XmlNode n in allFiles)
            {
                string fileName = n["NAME"].InnerText;
                string fileHash = n["CHECKSUM"].InnerText;
                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    this.allSize += Convert.ToInt32(XMLHandler.getSizeOfFile(fileName));
                    this.increaseDownloadNumber();

                    string[] temp = this.toDownloadFile;
                    this.toDownloadFile = new string[this.toDownloadNumber];
                    int curr_store_element = 0;
                    foreach (string curr_element in temp)
                    {
                        this.toDownloadFile[curr_store_element] = curr_element;
                        curr_store_element++;
                    }
                    this.addToDownloadList(fileName, curr_array_element);
                    curr_array_element++;

                }
```

Se eu editar xml, na seguinte forma, ai eu consigo ler

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML>
<PATCHINFO>
  <Name>Teste</Name>
  <SIZE>2962</SIZE>
  <CHECKSUM>4206740436</CHECKSUM>
 
 
</PATCHINFO>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações.

O que você está tentando obter é o atributo da tag `<PATCHNODE>`, portando quando diz:

```
string fileName = n["NAME"].InnerText;
```

Seria o conteúdo(texto) da tag `<NAME>` que nem existe.

Se foi bem o que eu entendi, você está tentando pegar o nome do arquivo, que neste caso é um atributo da tag `<PATCHNODE>`, me corrija se eu estiver errado. Seguindo minha resposta o correto é:

```
string fileName = n["PATCHNODE"].Attributes["file"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acesse o site http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ e cole o conteúdo do seu Xml lá, feito isto pega as classes c#, que ele gera para você.

Depois é só carregar o conteudo do seu xml em uma variavel, e deserializar o xml conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
string testData = @"<StepList>
                        <Step>
                            <Name>Name1</Name>
                            <Desc>Desc1</Desc>
                        </Step>
                        <Step>
                            <Name>Name2</Name>
                            <Desc>Desc2</Desc>
                        </Step>
                    </StepList>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StepList));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(testData))
{
    StepList result = (StepList) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Lembrando que onde diz typeof(StepList), StepList é o seu objeto root.